# Ckseditor with Knockout js binding issue

Tags: html, knockout.js, richtextbox

I need to have a Rich Text Area box to bind to knockout observable variable, I tried using Ckseditor control but the binding did not work even if I put a custom KO binding for CKSeditor. So I switched back to regular html textarea, then i can see the binding of the text, however it will show the text with html tags like this -

```
<p>This is the scope</p>
```

I would like to convert the textarea to a rich textarea control like cks or any other, anyone has any idea how to do it?

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.7/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="Scope">Scope</label>
                  <textarea rows="10" name="Scope" class="form-control input-sm" id="Scope" data-bind="value: Scope"></textarea> 
            </div>
```

Following is the Knockout observable variable code:

```
 self.Scope = ko.observable("<p>This is the scope</p>");
```

Answer (score 0):

In markup file, I didn't use the data-bind attribute to ckeditor textarea

```
            CKEDITOR.replace('Scope1');
            function GetFormatedTextFromDB(){
this.Scope1 = ko.observable($('#Scope1').val("<b>Murugesa Pandian test</b>"));
};
ko.applyBindings(new GetFormatedTextFromDB());
```

//pass your retrieved variable to val function
[Output from script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57ln0.png)